# How is it that an lrbox environment is correctly placing content in TOC

Tags: table-of-contents, hyperref

I was reviewing some old code that I wrote and thought I found a typo.  But nevertheless everything is working as I want it to.

The basic idea of the MWE here is that I'm storing content in a `lrbox` which I may or may not choose to use.  If I use it, I want there to be an entry in the table of contents.  If I don't use the `lrbox`, then I don't want any such entry.

Here's a MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\newif\ifusemybox
\usemyboxtrue
\newsavebox{\mytocitembox}
\newenvironment{mytocitem}[1]{%
    \begin{lrbox}{\mytocitembox}
      \phantomsection
      \addcontentsline{toc}{subsection}{#1}
      \begin{minipage}[t]{3in}
  }
  {%%
      \end{minipage}%%
    \end{lrbox}%%
    \ifusemybox
      \usebox{\mytocitembox}
    \fi
  }

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\section{A}

  \lipsum[1-5]

  \begin{mytocitem}{test for section A}
  \lipsum[5]
  \end{mytocitem}

  \lipsum[6-14]

\section{B}

  \usemyboxfalse

  \begin{mytocitem}{test for section B}
  \lipsum[10]
  \end{mytocitem}

\lipsum[5-10]

\end{document}
```

What I'm confused about is how `\phantomsection` is working here.
It seems to me that the proper way to write this should have been to use

```
      \ifusemybox
        \phantomsection
        \addcontentsline{toc}{subsection}{#1}
      \fi
```

in the definition of the environment (instead of what I actually did which was not to embed the `\phantomsection` etc. in a conditional).

Based upon my understanding of how `lrbox`es behave, I would have expected
that at the time of the creation of the `lrbox`, the `\phantomsection` would also have been produced **including** the `\addcontentsline`.  In fact, the more I think about this, the more complexed I become.

Could someone explain why my code works?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to distinguish between “codes”, but when a box is built *all* code is executed. However, some code might be executed in a way that could be mistaken for “not executed”.

I'm referring to code producing “whatsits”. An `\addcontentsline` instruction ultimately reduces to a `\write` (with the `.aux` file as output; later a similar `write` will be repeated to write on the `.toc` file).

A `\write` produces a whatsit that's appended to the list currently being built; for `lrbox` it's a horizontal list and a `\write` whatsit doesn't really belong to a horizontal list: it contains a pointer to a memory location where the fully expanded argument to `\write` is stored to be executed during a `\shipout` operation.

<sub>Note that an `\immediate\write` doesn't create a whatsit; as a matter of fact, an `\addcontentsline` instruction is a “delayed” `\write`.</sub>

So there are three cases:

1. the horizontal list is itself shipped out (quite unlikely)
2. the horizontal list is used while a vertical list is being built
3. the horizontal list is not used at all

Case 1 is unlikely because doing

```
\begin{lrbox}{\mytocitembox}
...
\end{lrbox}\shipout\box\mytocitembox
```

may be considered rather extravagant. So we're left with cases 2 and 3. In case 2 the whatsit will *migrate* to the enclosing vertical list (the migration process is described in chapter 24 and 25 of the TeXbook). In case 3 it will disappear into oblivion.

Almost the same happens with `\special` whatsits, with the difference that no migration takes place. But, again, if the horizontal list is never used (that is, delivered into another list), the `\special` will not have a location in the output file (DVI or PDF). The instruction `\phantomsection` executes a `\special` command (in the case of `pdflatex`, it is `\pdfdest`, which is quite similar).

If you add the code

```
{\tracingonline=1 \showboxdepth=1000 \showboxbreadth=1000 \showbox\mytocitembox}
```

before `\ifusemybox` and compile from a terminal, TeX will stop showing

```
> \box26=
\hbox(6.94444+0.0)x220.14333
.\penalty 10000
.\hbox(0.0+0.0)x0.0
..\hbox(0.0+0.0)x0.0, shifted -12.0
...\pdfdest name{section*.2} xyz
...\penalty 10000
.\write3{\protect \BOOKMARK [2][-]{section*.2}{test for section A}{section.1}%\ETC.}
.\write1{\@writefile{toc}{\protect \contentsline {subsection}{test for section\ETC.}
.\glue 3.33333 plus 1.66666 minus 1.11111
.\vbox(6.94444+0.0)x216.81
..\hbox(6.94444+0.0)x216.81, glue set 194.30995fil
...\hbox(0.0+0.0)x0.0
...\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 H
...\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 e
...\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 l
...\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 l
...\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 o
...\penalty 10000
...\glue(\parfillskip) 0.0 plus 1.0fil
...\glue(\rightskip) 0.0
```

In conclusion, such commands *are* executed, but the effect of this execution may not find its way in the output. So it's immaterial whether you put the `\phantomsection` or `\addcontentsline` instruction inside a `\ifusemybox` conditional.

Conversely, commands such as `\stepcounter` would be executed right when the box is being built; using the box is irrelevant: if you don't use a box built with `\sbox`, `\savebox` or `lrbox` or use it multiple times, a `\stepcounter` command inside it will be executed exactly once.

Comment: Thanks for the reminder about chapters 24 and 25.  So LaTeX is basically waiting until I use the box before *writing* anything?  That leads me to wonder how LaTeX handles garbage collection.  Do these *whatsits* disappear when I later reassign the box?  Or do they just clutter up memory?

Comment: @A.Ellett I don't know about this, but TeX (the program) is in charge of the garbage collection. I'm sure that `texdoc tex` will shed light, if you want to try it. ;-)

Comment: Yet another resource I was unaware of.  Thanks for the pointer to `texdoc tex`.  I didn't realize there was also documentation on the Pascal code.

Comment: @A.Ellett my understanding is that the memory will be reclaimed just as for all the other nodes in the box. there is not really any difference between whatsit and box nodes at that level: they are both just items in the horizontal or vertical list saved in the box.

Answer (score 6):

When the `lrbox` gets defined, it executes the code inside at the moment of the definition. We can see this from the following, where the `test` counter is incremented from the sole act of defining the box:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\newif\ifusemybox
\usemyboxtrue

\newcounter{test}
\def\TESTINLRBOX{\stepcounter{test}}

\newsavebox{\mytocitembox}
\newenvironment{mytocitem}[1]{%
    \begin{lrbox}{\mytocitembox}
      \TESTINLRBOX
      \phantomsection
      \addcontentsline{toc}{subsection}{#1}
      \begin{minipage}[t]{3in}
  }
  {%%
      \end{minipage}%%
    \end{lrbox}%%
    \ifusemybox
      \usebox{\mytocitembox}
    \fi
  }

\begin{document}\thispagestyle{empty}

\tableofcontents

\section{A}

  \begin{mytocitem}{test for section A}
  Hello
  \end{mytocitem}

\arabic{test}

\section{B}

\usemyboxfalse

  \begin{mytocitem}{test for section B}
  World
  \end{mytocitem}

\arabic{test}

\end{document}
```

Output:

> [image: lrbox1]

`\phantomsection` does indeed make global assignments, so when it gets executed this part of its action has the same effect as in our test.

Furthermore an **additional** `\phantomsection` is already done by `\addcontentsline` (current  versions of `hyperref`, and when one deals with `chapter`, `section`, `subsection`, ... which are known to `hyperref`). Your code without any `\phantomsection` works!

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\newif\ifusemybox

\let\oldphantomsection\phantomsection

\def\phantomsection{\stepcounter{test}\oldphantomsection}


\newcounter{test}

\newsavebox{\mytocitembox}
\newenvironment{mytocitem}[1]{%
    \begin{lrbox}{\mytocitembox}
%      \phantomsection
      \addcontentsline{toc}{subsection}{#1}
      \begin{minipage}[t]{3in}
  }
  {%%
      \end{minipage}%%
    \end{lrbox}%%
    \ifusemybox
%      \phantomsection
      \usebox{\mytocitembox}
    \fi
  }

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\section{A}

phantomsection has been done \arabic{test} times

\usemyboxfalse
  \begin{mytocitem}{test for section A}
  Hello
\end{mytocitem}

phantomsection has been done \arabic{test} times

% testing:

% @currentHref: \csname @currentHref\endcsname

% Hy@linkcounter: \the\csname Hy@linkcounter\endcsname

\section{B}

\usemyboxtrue

phantomsection has been done \arabic{test} times

  \begin{mytocitem}{test for section B}
  World
  \end{mytocitem}

phantomsection has been done \arabic{test} times

% @currentHref: \csname @currentHref\endcsname

% Hy@linkcounter: \the\csname Hy@linkcounter\endcsname

\end{document}
```

> [image: phantomsection]

---

This code has the following in its log file related to the added `\phantomsection`:

```
Package hyperref Warning: The anchor of a bookmark and its parent's must not
(hyperref)                 be the same. Added a new anchor on line 38.


Package hyperref Warning: The anchor of a bookmark and its parent's must not
(hyperref)                be the same. Added a new anchor on input line 56.
```

Comment: One might wonder then why the `\addcontentsline` which is automatically done as part of the `\section` code expansion does not do the `\phantomsection`? the answer is that `\addcontentsline` does the `\phantomsection` only under certain conditions (and besides `hyperref` also replaces `\@sect` by its own version; as a result the conditions for `\addcontentsline` to do the `\phantomsection` are not met then).

Comment: hmm to be completely honest I am not completely clear (in my mind) about when `hyperref` decides to add a `\phantomsection`. For example, if I add one more `\addcontentsline{toc}{subsection}{stuff}` after the second `\mytocitem` in the second code snippet, I observe that the missing (and necessary) `\phantomsection` is not added. As a result the `stuff` entry in the TOC will be linked to the wrong previous destination.

Comment: While this is interesting to know, I am not sure if it adresses the OPs question, which, to my understanding is: Why is the `\addcontentsline` **not** executed if the box is thrown away (that is, `\usemyboxfalse`).

Comment: @Daniel In my answer I focused on the `\phantomsection` which seemed to perplex the most the OP, in my first reading. I came back to add a bit to my answer, and then saw how `egreg` had clearly explained that the `\addcontentsline` *is* executed, but that the `whatsit` originating from it only makes it to real life (i.e. to the page being shipped out) if the box is used, thus answering your (rightful) concern.

Comment: +1 Very thorough explanation of `\phantomsection`.  I wasn't aware that `\addcontentsline` could be used without a previous call to `\phantomsection`.  But other than this, you're telling me what I already know, which still leaves the questions:  why is the effects of these two commands not executed in the final document given how `lrbox`es are built?

Comment: @A.Ellett  `egreg`'s answer explains that commands are executed but sometimes the effect may be nil (here, the horizontal box not being used, the `whatsit` it contains which is supposed to write something to the `.aux` file, which is an instruction to write something to the `.toc` file is never shipped out so the `.aux` file is not changed hence the `.toc` file neither)

Answer (score 2):

The contents of the box is executed with `\usebox`, not before. So your example works.

However, I would use it this way:

```
\newenvironment{mytocitem}[1]
  {%
    \def\mytocentry{#1}%
    \begin{lrbox}{\mytocitembox}
    \begin{minipage}[t]{3in}
  }{%%
    \end{minipage}%%
    \end{lrbox}%%
    \ifusemybox
      \phantomsection
      \addcontentsline{toc}{subsection}{\mytocentry}%
      \usebox{\mytocitembox}%
    \fi
  }
```

Comment: I don't think your first assertion is true. `\documentclass{article}
\newcounter{herbert}
\begin{document}
\theherbert
\begin{lrbox}{0}\stepcounter{herbert}H\end{lrbox}
\theherbert
\usebox{0}
\theherbert
\end{document}` prints “0 1H 1” (as it should).

Comment: that is a completely other case of using a box!

Comment: It contradicts your statement, which is wrong. The code inside `\setbox\name=\hbox{...}` (ultimately this is what `lrbox` does) is fully executed and macros are completely expanded. The execution of delayed writes consists in storing the completely expanded code to be processed later, if and when this write is scanned during a shipout operation. Hiding the `\write` in the conditional is completely useless. Following your statement, `\stepcounter` instructions would be executed as many times as the box is used, which doesn't happen.

Comment: read what I wrote: I said that your statement with a counter is another issue!

Comment: Read your statement. I'm finishing here, hoping you'll delete this answer or correct it.